# print() vs debugPrint() in Swift

Tags: swift, methods, printing

This might be a simple question but because of a lack of understanding about the difference between [print()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/print(_:separator:terminator:)) and [debugPrint()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/debugprint(_:separator:terminator:)) in Swift I am unable to understand where to use each one.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You use debugPrint when you want more information about what is being printed to the console. The additional information is usually useful for debugging.

[print()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541053-print) - Writes the textual representations of the given items into the standard output.

[debugPrint()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1539920-debugprint) -  Writes the textual representations of the given items most suitable for debugging into the standard output.

**Basically debugPrint adds additional information that is useful for debugging like type information etc.**

An example:

```
print(1...5)
// Prints "1...5"


debugPrint(1...5)
// Prints "CountableClosedRange(1...5)"
```

Comment: Also debugPrint prints things like \n \t as is, without formatting the text. So if you want to see pretty json for example, you should use print.

Answer (score 28):

Using `print()` is a regular way to visualy see what you are creating. It does not show 'irrelevant' information that is not neccesary to represent the printed variable.

e.g.

```
print("test")
// prints: test
```

Using `debugPrint()` however adds the inferred type to the output.

e.g.

```
debugPrint("test")
// prints: "test"
```

Note how it adds the quotation marks to let you know it is a string.

Erica Sadun has created a perfect example of how these two functions differ: 
[Swift: Logging](http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/22/swift-logging/)

Answer (score 19):

Article link : [print-vs-debugprint](https://medium.com/@abhishekbedi/print-vs-debugprint-eac33a774d5a)

If You make a network call and do a `debugPrint(response)` instead of `print(response)`, you will get a lot more valuable information.
See the below example code:

**Sample Code** :  *Using iTunes Search Api*

```
    let urlReq = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=1")!)

    Alamofire.request(urlReq).responseJSON { (data) in
        print(data)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        debugPrint(data)
    }
```

**Console Output** (Removing some of the response fields)

For **print**

```
SUCCESS: {
    resultCount = 1;
    results =     (
                {
            artistId = 909253;
            artistName = "Jack Johnson";
            artistViewUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/jack-johnson/id909253?uo=4";
        }
    );
}
```

For **debugPrint**

```
[Request]: GET https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=1
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x610000223860> { URL: https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=1 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=86345";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename=1.txt";
    "Content-Length" = 1783;
    "Content-Type" = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 23 Sep 2017 14:29:11 GMT";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Apple-Partner" = "origin.0";
    "X-Cache" = "TCP_MISS from a23-76-156-143.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/9.1.0.4-20866905) (-)";
    "X-Cache-Remote" = "TCP_MISS from a23-45-232-92.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/9.1.0.4-20866905) (-)";
    "X-True-Cache-Key" = "/L/itunes.apple.com/search ci2=limit=1&term=jack+johnson__";
    "apple-originating-system" = MZStoreServices;
    "apple-seq" = 0;
    "apple-timing-app" = "86 ms";
    "apple-tk" = false;
    "x-apple-application-instance" = 1000492;
    "x-apple-application-site" = NWK;
    "x-apple-jingle-correlation-key" = VEF3J3UWCHKUSGPHDZRI6RB2QY;
    "x-apple-orig-url" = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=1";
    "x-apple-request-uuid" = "a90bb4ee-9611-d549-19e7-1e628f443a86";
    "x-apple-translated-wo-url" = "/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/wsSearch?term=jack+johnson&limit=1&urlDesc=";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-webobjects-loadaverage" = 0;
} }
[Data]: 1783 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    resultCount = 1;
    results =     (
                {
            artistId = 909253;
            artistName = "Jack Johnson";
            artistViewUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/jack-johnson/id909253?uo=4";
        }
    );
}

[Timeline]: Timeline: 

{
  "Request Start Time": 527869893.013,
  "Initial Response Time": 527869893.033,
  "Request Completed Time": 527869893.034,
  "Serialization Completed Time": 527869893.035,
  "Latency": 0.020secs,
  "Request Duration": 0.021secs,
  "Serialization Duration": 0.001secs,
  "Total Duration": 0.021secs
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you both implementation `CustomDebugStringConvertible` and `CustomStringConvertible` protocol, then `debugPrint` method default use `debugDescription` content, and `print` method default use `description` content.

Answer (score 1):

debugPrint() Writes the textual representations of the given items most suitable for debugging into the standard output and it consists of several parameters:

```
func debugPrint(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n")
```

**items**:
can include zero or more item to print.

**separator**: A string to print between each item. The default is a single space (" ").

**terminator**: The string to print after all items have been printed. The default is a newline ("\n").

I have written some examples below for more understanding:

```
debugPrint("One two three four five")
// Prints "One two three four five"

debugPrint(1...5)
// Prints "ClosedRange(1...5)"

debugPrint(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
// Prints "1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0"
```

To print the items separated by something other than a space, pass a string as separator.

```
debugPrint(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, separator: " ... ")
// Prints "1.0 ... 2.0 ... 3.0 ... 4.0 ... 5.0"
```

The output from each call to debugPrint(_:separator:terminator:) includes a newline by default. To print the items without a trailing newline, pass an empty string as terminator or pass any other things you want.

```
for n in 1...5 {
    debugPrint(n, terminator: "")
}
// Prints "12345"
```